# base32 encode in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk, base32

Trying to find a way to do base32 encoding in Lua, specifically for the Corona SDK.

I have found this library:

https://github.com/b4ldr/nselib/blob/master/base32.lua

But it seems to require a "bin" library that does not come with Corona SDK and I am not able to find in anywhere on the web.

So, does someone know how to fix the "bin" dependancy or another base32 lib that works with Corona SDK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**basexx**](https://github.com/aiq/basexx) library supports base32 encoding and decoding, and does not have any dependencies.